# r logical condition for "any of" operation

Tags: r, logical-operators

This is probably a very basic R question...and feel a bit bad about asking...but is there a bit of code like `==` or `|` or `!` or `&` etc that carries out the following logical function?

if

`x` == any of the value of the elements/contained in vector `y`

then TRUE

else

FALSE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually pretty close to exactly what you said.

```
any(x == y)
```

That can work for any length of x and y although it will throw a warning if x and y aren't multiples of each other in length.  It would be best if x and y are the same length.  However, for the limited case of x being one item then

```
x %in% y
```

will also work.  And, if you have an x that is not the same length as y but greater than 1 item long the following is probably most sensible.

```
any(x %in% y)
```

Comment: Thank you! especially like the extension if x is longer than 1

Comment: I don't quite agree with this answer and personally think liuminzhao's answer is more along the lines of what the question is asking for.  I think this works fine if either x or y are of length 1 but past that this doesn't do what the original question describes.

Comment: Where does this not work?  My first and last versions will work with any length x and y.  That makes them safer in case you just get the order mixed up.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
x %in% y
```

where `y` is the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the intersect function if x is a vector and y is a vector and you want to see all values that are in both vectors. This will also work if either x or y are scalars.

```
# Sample Data
x <- 1:40
y <- 35:100

# We know that 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 are in both vectors
intersect(x, y)
[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

I don't know the exact problem you are trying to solve, but this may be useful to you assuming you need to know which values are in y.

If you just need a TRUE/FALSE answer without a seeing a boolean vector that you would get using x %in% y, you can use this:

```
length(intersect(x, y)) > 0
[1] TRUE
```